# How to add a counter into bubble Sort to count the number comparison?

Tags: c++, counter

Taking the following code into account:

```
int CountBubbleSort=0;
template <typename Comparable>
void bubbleSort(vector<Comparable*> &v)
{
    bool sorted = false;
    for(int pass = 1; pass < v.size() && !sorted; pass++)
    {
        sorted = true;
        for(int i = 0; i < v.size() - pass; i++)
        {
            if(*v[i + 1] < *v[i])
            {
                swap(v, i, i + 1);
                CountBubbleSort++;
                sorted = false;

            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"bubbleSort comparison is "<<CountBubbleSort<<endl;
}
```

when I call the function, why is the output of `CountBubbleSort` "0", what is the problem?

Comment: Is your input already sorted? You're not counting the number of comparisons, you're counting the number of swaps.

Answer (score 4):

```
void bubbleSort(vector<Comparable*> &v)
{
    bool sorted = false;
    for(int pass = 1; pass < v.size() && !sorted; pass++)
    {
        sorted = true;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < v.size() - pass; i++)
        {
            if(*v[i + 1] < *v[i])
            {
                swap(v, i, i + 1);
                sorted = false;

            }
        }
        CountBubbleSort += i;
    }
    cout<<"bubbleSort comparison is "<<CountBubbleSort<<endl;
}
```

To count the number of comparaisons, you just have to add your inner i (at each second-loop you do i compraison) to your countBubble at each turn of your first loop.

Comment: Shouldn't `CountBubbleSort += i;` be inside the second for-loop?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis  You could put it inside the second for-loop but i think it's better to add one time rather than iterate throught that counter at each turn.

Comment: Good catch to use += i

Comment: Excuse my logic error! This still won't compile though, the `i` is only declared inside the for-loop. You would have to declare it outside.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis oh yeah, what a silly error of me, i have fixed it. Did not notice the scope :D

Comment: @Mekap Now it seems to be correct as far as I can tell, good answer!